# Encounter ORA-6502 error when trying to execute a package wihin a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

During the firing of the trigger, two packages must be executed. Encounter `ORA-6502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` on the first call to package 1.

The Package `SETFLELDRC` Compiled successfully and when executed outside the trigger does work!

It DOES NOT execute the code for the package at all.

The Code

```
DROP TRIGGER SETPROC.SLCFILEARRIVE_TRG;
```

create package goes here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SETPROC.SLCFILEARRIVE_TRG
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON SET_LOADER_CNTL
 REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

    v_MAIN_LODR_APP                 VARCHAR2(30) := Null;
    v_RECEIVE_FILENAME              VARCHAR2(20) := Null;      
    v_FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI             VARCHAR2(01) := 'N';
    v_SERVICE                       VARCHAR2(04) := Null;
    v_SUBSERVICE                    VARCHAR2(05) := Null;
    v_Centre                        VARCHAR2(03) := Null;
    v_Currency                      VARCHAR2(03) := Null;

    v_servcntl_prddate              VARCHAR2(08) := Null;
    v_servcntl_serv                 VARCHAR2(08) := 'SET';

    v_prg                           VARCHAR2(10)  := RPAD(REPLACE('SLCFLEARRV','x',' '),10,' ');
    v_vrs                           VARCHAR2(02)  := '04';
    v_spo                           VARCHAR2(03)  := 'SET';  
    v_spomsg                        VARCHAR2(200) := Null;

    v_loader_parameter              VARCHAR2(50)  := Null;
    v_loader_parameter1             VARCHAR2(50)  := Null;
    v_loader_parameter2             VARCHAR2(50)  := Null;    

    v_trace                         VARCHAR2(06)  := Null;  

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''YYYYMMDD''';

    :NEW.SERVICE        := RTRIM(:NEW.SERVICE);
    :NEW.SUB_SERVICE    := RTRIM(NVL(:NEW.SUB_SERVICE,'NONE'));

    v_SERVICE           := RTRIM(:NEW.SERVICE);
    v_SUBSERVICE        := RTRIM(:NEW.SUB_SERVICE);
    v_trace := 'SLC002';
    v_MAIN_LODR_APP     := RTRIM(:NEW.MAIN_LODR_APP);
    v_trace := 'SLC003';     
    v_RECEIVE_FILENAME  := RTRIM(:NEW.RECEIVE_FILENAME);
    v_trace := 'SLC004';    
    v_FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI := :NEW.FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI;
    v_Centre            := :NEW.CENTRE;
    v_Currency          := :NEW.CURRENCY;

    IF :NEW.FILE_ARRIVED = 'Y' AND NVL(:OLD.FILE_ARRIVED,'N') <> 'Y' then

       --Call to First Package ... FAILS HERE...

        SETFLELDRC.Main_Process(v_SERVICE, 
                                v_SUBSERVICE, 
                                v_Centre, 
                                v_Currency, 
                                v_RECEIVE_FILENAME, 
                                v_FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI
                               );

        v_trace := 'SLC06e';        
        :NEW.FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI := v_FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI;
        v_trace := 'SLC06f';        
        v_spomsg := 'Loader Completed for ('||v_SERVICE||' '||v_SUBSERVICE
                    ||' '||v_Centre||' '||v_Currency
                    ||' '||v_RECEIVE_FILENAME||') - Status = ('||v_FILETYPE_HSCT_VLI||')';
        Spo_Write(v_prg, v_spo, v_vrs, v_spomsg);      
    END IF;

    v_trace := 'SLC06g';

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20310,SQLERRM||'SLCFILEARRIVE Trigger ERROR');
END;
/
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur

Comment: Most probably that somewhere string to number autocast occurs which fails due to value not being numeric or other type cast exception.

Comment: i think the lot of null-initializations are unnecessary, but confusing

Comment: autonomous transactions have to have a commit in them but you may receive a "no commits in triggers" error.  The whole trigger code should be replaced with a call to a packaged procedure